# Angular2 observable & post - access response

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services

Im a bit new to Observables, i have successfully sent a POST api request and received a correct JSON response:

```
{"id":138,"date":"2017-02-23T05:10:18"}
```

But im unsure how to access this response and do something with it. Here is my post service:

```
  // sends a media(file blob) object to WP API
  updateMedia(file: File): Observable<File> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, Content-Disposition',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename='+file.name, 
        'Authorization': 'Basic cmh5c0B0aGVpdHRlYW0uY29tLmF1OkRlc3Ryb3lfMSE='
    }); 
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

    return this.http.post(BASE_API, file, options)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
```

And here is my Observable:

```
  onUpdateMedia(file: File) {
    this.mediaService
      .updateMedia(file)
      .subscribe((
        file: File) => {
        this.file = Object.assign({}, this.file, event);
      });
    console.log(event); //hmm not what i want
  }
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the response from the map observable and than you will be able to get in the `subscribe` listner. like this

```
 // sends a media(file blob) object to WP API
  updateMedia(file: File): Observable<File> {
      ............

    return this.http.post(BASE_API, file, options)
    .map((response: Response) => return {res : response.json(), status : response.status});
  }


   onUpdateMedia(file: any) {
    this.mediaService
      .updateMedia(file)
      .subscribe((file: any) => {
        console.log(file, "Response from Post Request Here....")
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response is of Object type. Assign the response in a object type of variable.

```
 my_res:any;
  onUpdateMedia(file: File) {
    this.mediaService
      .updateMedia(file)
      .subscribe((
        data: any) => {
        this.my_res=data
      });

  }
```